# compiling and linking miracl c++

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a problem with compiling and linking miracl library.

When I'm trying to compile and link miracl while using cmake I'm getting weird error messages about the miracl.h file like :

```
error: expected initializer before ‘mr_large’
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(OS-PSI)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -maes -O3 -mavx")

include_directories($ENV{HOME}/libscapi/lib/Miracl/include)

find_library(
        LIBMIRACL
        NAMES miracl
        PATHS $ENV{HOME}/libscapi/install/lib/
        NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)


set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(OS-PSI ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(OS-PSI ${LIBMIRACL})
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <miracl.h>
#include <mirdef.h>
#include <ecn.h>
#include <big.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Big big1(12);
    int partyId = atoi(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

All I'm trying to do is to create a simple program that using miracl library

Comment: Rework the `target_link_libraries` call. It doesn't help repeating libraries ;-) Try to use `find_library` for finding the correct path to the miracl library. Side note: You should never use relative include paths in `#include` directives. Solve that with specifying include directories via `target_include_directories`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem after i post it on miracl GitHub at this [link](https://github.com/miracl/MIRACL/issues/28#issuecomment-241359625)

The solution is to change `__int64` to `long long` at `mirdef.h`

Comment: If you did install miracle on ubuntu/linux, could you help me to install? I followed the documentation but unable to compile the programs.

Answer (score 1):

The error you show is a compilation error which appears to come from one of the Miracl headers. A quick look at the [documentation](https://certivox.org/display/EXT/2.+Installation) shows it's a C library not C++ so it recommends:

```
extern "C"
{
     #include "miracl.h"
}
```

also going on to say

> although in most cases it will be preferable to use the C++ wrapper classes described in Chapter 7.

so I'd suggest you have a look at the [documentation](https://certivox.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7635919) of the C++ interface. If I understand their example correctly, it looks like you simply don't have to include `miracl.h`, `mirdef.h` and `ecn.h` for your example in C++.

After you fixed that issue, for linking the library, something like the following using [`find_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html)should work, update paths to be absolute and update `/path/to/libscapi...` to your actual path:

```
find_library(
    LIBMIRACL
    NAMES miracl
    PATHS /path/to/libscapi/install/lib/
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)
```

You can then link your library by using:

```
target_link_libraries(OS-PSI ${LIBMIRACL})
```

Also you could fix your includes by adding the `Miracl/include` directory to your include path:

```
include_directories(/path/to/libscapi/lib/Miracl/include)
```

and then you can use the following, which allows your program to compile with different installation paths:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <big.h>
```

Comment: After the changes and remove miracl.h mirdef.h and ecn.h, I have the same problem.

Comment: @liorko there is no issue I can see in the posted code and CMakeLists.txt. Maybe you should ask on the miracl tracker directly https://github.com/miracl/MIRACL/issues ?

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I will ask there